# MongoDB Tree with Array of Ancestors design

Tags: mongodb, tree

I have a question regarding how to design a tree of Ancestors in MongoDB.

For example if we have this:

```
{ "_id" : "ACL", "ancestors" : [ ], "parent" : null }
{ "_id" : "apps", "ancestors" : [ "ACL" ], "parent" : "ACL" }
{ "_id" : "3222", "ancestors" : [ "ACL", "apps" ], "parent" : "apps" }
{ "_id" : "1223", "ancestors" : [ "ACL", "apps" ], "parent" : "apps" }
```

This means we have a tree like this

```
       ACL      
        |       
      Apps      
     /    \     
   3222  1223
```

I would like to have a node of "users" under each node. However, given that _id must be UNIQUE, I can't do so.

```
       ACL      
        |       
      Apps      
     /    \     
   3222  1223   
  /         \   
users      users
```

How would you go around this?

Edit: I have read the Model Tree information on MongoDB here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to deal with your situation, unless you don't use "_id" as unique tree node, you can consider this schema:

```
{ "_id" : ["unique guid":xxx, "tree node": "users"], "ancestors" : [ ], "parent" : null }
{ "_id" : ["unique guid":xxx, "tree node": "users"], "ancestors" : [ "ACL" ], "parent" : "ACL" }
```